# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'tuple'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"}), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

dense_layers = [0, 1, 2]
layer_sizes = [32, 64, 128]
conv_layers = [1, 2, 3]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            Name = "{}-conv-{}dense-{}-units".format(conv_layer, dense_layer, layer_size)
            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir = 'logs/{}'.format(Name))
            
            model = Sequential()
            
            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = x_train.shape[0:]))
            model.add(Activation("relu"))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
            
            x_train = x_train.shape[0:]
            
            for i in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3),))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
                
            model.add(Flatten())
            
            for i in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))
                model.add(Dropout(0.2))
                
            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
            
            model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
            model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 30, epochs = 10)
                      
model.save("MNIST CNN")
```

> -->model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 30, epochs = 10) ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class
> 'tuple'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"}), <class
> 'numpy.ndarray'>

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model to me just feels wrong:

1. Firstly you are using `Conv2D` on the data with shape `(batch_size, 28, 28)` shape expected is `(batch_size, 28, 28, color_channels)`
2. Secondly you are using `binary_cross_entropy` for a multi-class classification `binary_cross_entropy` is only used when we have two outcomes.

How to solve your problem?

Change the input pipeline by reshaping `features` in the expectes shape as follows:

```py
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
```

Change the Conv2D input shape in your function

```py
model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]))
```

Change the output layer units to `10` since you are classifying 10 classes:

```py
 model.add(Dense(10))
```

During model combilation you can use either `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` or `categorical_crossentropy` as your loss. But note that `categorical_crossentropy` expect labels to be `one_hot` encoded so in your case you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Your new code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

dense_layers = [0, 1, 2]
layer_sizes = [32, 64, 128]
conv_layers = [1, 2, 3]
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            Name = "{}-conv-{}dense-{}-units".format(conv_layer, dense_layer, layer_size)
            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir = 'logs/{}'.format(Name))
            
            model = Sequential()
            
            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]))
            model.add(Activation("relu"))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
            for i in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3),))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
                
            model.add(Flatten())
            
            for i in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))
                model.add(Dropout(0.2))
                
            model.add(Dense(10))
            model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
            print(model.summary())
            
            model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer = "adam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
            model.fit(x_test, y_test, batch_size = 30, epochs = 10)
                      
model.save("MNIST CNN")
```